# Creating cURL POST request for API in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, curl, post

I'm having some trouble getting a POST request to fire off for an app which we are currently using on a Shopify store.

Essentially, we need to have the following request post to the LoyaltyLion API in order for customers to obtain a reward.

Here's what the cURL request looks like:

```
  curl -X POST \
 --user 'abc123:abc123' \
 --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 --url 'https://api.loyaltylion.com/v2/activities' \
 --data '{
   "name": "qr_code",
   "customer_id": "12345",
   "customer_email": "person@customer.com",
   "merchant_id": "12345"
 }'
```

I've been reading some docs, and this is what I've come up with. I haven't had any luck getting this to fire off on the front end though.

```
   $.ajax({
url: "https://api.loyaltylion.com/v2/activities'",
beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("abc123:abc123")); 
},
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json',
processData: false,
data: '{"name": "qr_code", 
        "customer_id": "12345",
        "customer_email": "person@customer.com",
        "merchant_id": "12345"
        }',
success: function (data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
},
error: function(){
  alert("Cannot get data");
}
});
```

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Try to remove the single quotes wrapping the data.

Comment: My apologies for the delay - looks like that did the trick. Thank you!